# Implementing websocket multi-rooms in Tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

There's few examples in Tomcat8 implementing multi-chat rooms. My codes are from tomcat8 examples. But there's only a websocket that everyone connect to it. My questions are, how to dispatch users to different rooms, and limit each room to 2 users?

Here's ChatAnnotation.java

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/websocket/chat")
public class ChatAnnotation {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ChatAnnotation.class);

    private static final Set<ChatAnnotation> connections =
            new CopyOnWriteArraySet<>();

    private String player;

    private Session session;

    public ChatAnnotation() {

    }

    @OnOpen
    public void start(Session session) {
        this.session = session;
        connections.add(this);
        String message = String.format("* %s %s", player, "has joined.");
        broadcast(message);
    }


    @OnClose
    public void end() {
        connections.remove(this);
        String message = String.format("* %s %s",
                player, "has disconnected.");
        broadcast(message);
    }


    @OnMessage
    public void incoming(String message) {
        String filteredMessage = String.format("%s: %s",
                player, HTMLFilter.filter(message.toString()));
        broadcast(filteredMessage);
    }




    @OnError
    public void onError(Throwable t) throws Throwable {
        log.error("Chat Error: " + t.toString(), t);
    }


    private static void broadcast(String msg) {
        for (ChatAnnotation client : connections) {
            try {
                synchronized (client) {
                    client.session.getBasicRemote().sendText(msg);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.debug("Chat Error: Failed to send message to client", e);
                connections.remove(client);
                try {
                    client.session.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // Ignore
                }
                String message = String.format("* %s %s",
                        client.player, "has been disconnected.");
                broadcast(message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Chat.jsp

```
<jsp:useBean id="chatannotation" scope="application" class="websocket.chat.ChatAnnotation" />
<%@ page import="websocket.chat.ChatAnnotation" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>tomcat 8 websocket example</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        input#chat {
            width: 410px
        }

        #console-container {
            width: 400px;
        }

        #console {
            border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
            border-right-color: #999999;
            border-bottom-color: #999999;
            height: 170px;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            padding: 5px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #console p {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
   </style>
    <script type="application/javascript">
        "use strict";

        var Chat = {};

        Chat.socket = null;

        Chat.connect = (function(host) {
            if ('WebSocket' in window) {
                Chat.socket = new WebSocket(host);
            } else if ('MozWebSocket' in window) {
                Chat.socket = new MozWebSocket(host);
            } else {
                Console.log('Error: WebSocket is not supported by this browser.');
                return;
            }

            Chat.socket.onopen = function () {
                Console.log('Info: WebSocket connection opened.');
                document.getElementById('chat').onkeydown = function(event) {
                    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                        Chat.sendMessage();
                    }
                };
            };

            Chat.socket.onclose = function () {
                document.getElementById('chat').onkeydown = null;
                Console.log('Info: WebSocket closed.');
            };

            Chat.socket.onmessage = function (message) {
                Console.log(message.data);
            };
        });

        Chat.initialize = function() {
            if (window.location.protocol == 'http:') {
                Chat.connect('ws://' + window.location.host + '/websocket/websocket/chat');
            } else {
                Chat.connect('wss://' + window.location.host + '/websocket/websocket/chat');
            }
        };

        Chat.sendMessage = (function() {
            var message = document.getElementById('chat').value;
            if (message != '') {
                Chat.socket.send(message);
                document.getElementById('chat').value = '';
            }
        });

        var Console = {};

        Console.log = (function(message) {
            var console = document.getElementById('console');
            var p = document.createElement('p');
            p.style.wordWrap = 'break-word';
            p.innerHTML = message;
            console.appendChild(p);
            while (console.childNodes.length > 25) {
                console.removeChild(console.firstChild);
            }
            console.scrollTop = console.scrollHeight;
        });

        Chat.initialize();

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <input type="text" placeholder="type and press enter to chat" id="chat" />
    </p>
    <div id="console-container">
        <div id="console"/>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```